# Dart Timer Seemingly Doesn't Fire

Tags: timer, dart, flutter

For some reason, the timer I made in Dart seems to not fire, as it doesn't change the screen contents. I had it working at one point, but it was gradually getting faster and faster for some reason (ticking more times per second, every second it ticked,) and I had to work on it.
[Here's a link to the main.dart file.](https://github.com/Lloyd7113/TappingGame/blob/master/main.dart)

Can anyone explain what I did wrong here? My placement of the tick function, perhaps?

Comment: Please provide the minimal code that you think is causing the problem.

Comment: Make gameTimer a member variable of one of the StatefulWidgets. Create it *once* in initState, and cancel it in dispose too.